# What can I use to edit scientific graphs (lines, arrows, boxes, etc)?

Tags: python, graphs, vector-graphics

I'm writing a MESA report and I have a lot of graphs that I want to label appropriately and explain in the report. This means including arrows, dotted lines, boxes, text, etc.

Any suggestions for what I can use?

(I understand that this might be a relatively amateur question but any answers would be helpful)

Comment: I often use Visio to add labels and callouts to images. If you can access the graph as an image format that doesn't suffer from compression issues (BMP, GIF, etc). I usually work with PNG format images.

Comment: @Ring Ah, thank you! I also discovered Vectr in the process of hunting for software and I think it also does a pretty good basic job of labeling. I'll check out Visio for my next upcoming project.

Comment: Visio might be overkill, though. It's lots more than something for labels.